SCCM - WinPE - "Unable to download PXE variable file" in SMSTS.Log
I am having an issue in Windows PE when trying to build a Dell XPS 8960 via SCCM. The device PXE boots into the WinPE environment without issue, but then it stops before any GUI's are displayed and all i can see is our custom WinPE background. There is nothing else on the screen. It's not frozen, as i can summon command prompt via the F8 key, but the config manager build GUI isn't visible.
I have checked the SMSTS.Log from the machine and i can see the following error:
Unable to download PXE variable file. Exit code=14. Will retry after 15 sec ...

After retrying for 6 or 7 times, it posts a failure log in SMSTS stating:
PxeGetPxeData failed with 0x8004016c

I'm almost certain this is due to missing network drivers in the boot image, and i have already injected every network driver for this model into the boot image already. However, nothing has changed and i am not sure what the issue is.
Does anyone have any ideas?

In my experience your suspicion seems very plausible, you can semi confirm this by summoning cmd and checking if you got an ip via ipconfig, If you do not even see any sort of device you are missing network drivers, if you see a device but it does not have a valid ip you have something like a duplicate use of the ip. If it is a missing network driver I would recommend booting one of the devices with dells default windows checking the exact driver name and version and verifying if it is present in this version via inspection of the boot image in sccm. also keep in mind pe might be win11
